# How can I open any PDF link on a page in a popup Lightbox?

Tags: pdf, lightbox

I will have a page that will regularly updated by a client (using something like TinyMCE), adding links to PDF files that I want to open in a lightbox on the page. Does code to make this a lightbox need to have the link of each PDF inside it or will the code cover any PDF links on the page? I am relativly new to lightboxes in general and was wondering if this is possible, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I believe PDF is too much for lightbox, use [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) with iframes instead.